# How do I insert inline code snippets on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm sorry for having to make a post to ask this, but I looked in all the documentation. If there's a link with finite details on posting techniques/code, please provide! Thanks.

I simply want to emulate what four spaces engages via code snippets, but I'd like to know how to include these snippets inline with text rather than a block like the four spaces enables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @KevinPaulKalis I didn't know meta.* existed. Thanks for that.

Comment: @MadsHansen Thanks for this URL.

Comment: `test` Testing to see if code works in comments. Pretty sure it's turned off.

Comment: test  <br/> test

Comment: How can we see which SO code will work in comments? inline code snippets seem to work.

Comment: No HTML works in comments. Comments only support "mini-markdown", which includes bold, italic, inline code formatting, and links.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use backticks (`) to create inline code, like `this` (produced by `this`).